# Powershell convert man page to html

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Im a noob with Powershell, I need help converting a specific man page into an html document

about_script

my code is: 
get-help about_scripts | convertto-html > scr.html

it creates an html page but it doesn't have most of the data in just the first couple of lines and a number showing how long it is.

can someone help by telling me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel? PowerShell has all the documentation online already..

[about_Scripts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847841.aspx)

You can find the help files for all the cmdlets. For 3rd party modules, documentation is usually included or available online.

[All PowerShell Core modules](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847741.aspx)

Comment: But for someone writing 3rd party scripts, cmdlet, modules, &c, this doesn't answer the question asked: How to convert the `Get-Help` output into HTML.

Comment: The point is that you shouldn't convert existing third-party help like `about_Scripts` above to HTML - that's the job of the developer. For the developers, take a look at [platyPS](https://github.com/PowerShell/platyPS) which can create markdown that you in turn can publish or convert to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
ConvertTo-HTML -Body "<p>$(Get-Help about_scripts)</p>" | Out-File aboutscripts.html
```

Start [Here](http://powershell.com/cs/)

Comment: This is not a very good answer because the formatting is so bad.